# Testing promise in Jasmine and not resolving- getting Expected undefined to be object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am new to testing and I am testing some angular code with jasmine. The mock promise I have created isn't resolving.  Here is the block of code that I am testing:

```
    $scope.init = function() {
    EngageService.getGrouping($stateParams.gid).then(function(res) {
      $scope.grouping = res.data;
      $scope.parent_id = $scope.grouping.parent != null ? $scope.grouping.parent.id : null;
      $scope.startDate = $scope.grouping.startDate ? new Date($scope.grouping.startDate) : new Date()
      $scope.endDate = $scope.grouping.endDate ? new Date($scope.grouping.endDate) : new Date()
      $scope.nda = $scope.grouping.nda == "No" ? false : true;
      $scope.grouping.invitation = $scope.grouping.invitateOnly == true ? 'true' : 'false';
      $scope.canManageGrouping = UserService.memberships[$scope.grouping.id].role.canManageGrouping;
      $scope.canCreateGroup = UserService.memberships[$scope.grouping.id].role.canCreateGroup;
    })
    EngageService.getProjects().then(function(res) {
      $scope.projects = res.data.rows;
    })
  }
```

and here is the code for testing the promise

```
describe('Tests for WorkspaceEdit', functio
  var getGroupingPromise;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('iq4App');
    return inject(function($injector) {
      this.EngageService = {
        getGrouping: function(gid) {
          getGroupingPromise = $q.defer();
          console.log(getGroupingPromise.promise)
          return getGroupingPromise.promise;
        }
      };
      this.scope = this.rootScope.$new();
      this.scope.$digest();
    });      '$upload': this.upload,
        'ResourceService': this.ResourceService,
        'MatchService': this.MatchService
      });
      this.scope.$digest();
    });


  });


      });

      it('should set stuff on init', function() {

        var fakeData = {
          data: {
            parent: {
              id: 3
            }
          }
        }

        this.scope.init();
        this.scope.$digest();
        getGroupingPromise.resolve(fakeData.data)
        expect(this.scope.grouping).toBe(fakeData.data);


      })

    });
```

I am trying to resolve some fake data to $scope.grouping but the data is resolving as undefined.  I know the promise is being created from my console.log in the getGrouping method in this.EngageService.  I've stripped out a lot of code that I didn't think was relevant but let me know if you want more detail.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the digest have to go after the resolve? Also posting a bit more source code might help.

Comment: I tried that as well but it did not work.  I will edit my original post to include more code from my test

Answer (score 1):

You need to *resolve the promise* with the fake data:

```
getGroupingPromise = $q.defer();
getGroupingPromise.resolve(fakeData.data); 
return getGroupingPromise.promise;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I was playing around with the code and accidentally deleted the part with the resolve but I put it back in (edited my original post as well) and get the same result.  Do you have any other thoughts?  I await your response.

Answer (score 1):

The digest in my test had to go after the resolve and not before.